# How to check whether data or object already exist in PList, iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I can add and remove an object or data in PList successfully but I wanna know that the data or an object already exist in PList. my code is

```
NSUInteger countObjectsFromPList;
countObjectsFromPList = [[mdict allKeys] count];
NSLog(@"objects in PList %d", countObjectsFromPList);
for(int i=0; i <= countLawsFromPList; i++){
NSLog(@"\n\n\n%d\n\n\n", i);
//if([objectName isEqualToString:[[mdict allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]])
if(objectName ==[[mdict allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]){
NSLog(@"Already exists");
//NSLog("String is equal");
}
else { 
NSLog(@"Added to Favorites");
} 
}
```

Please any one help me to over come this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the code answers, but they turned out to not be helpful for me. I corrected my code to be:

```
mdict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self doccumentspath]];
NSUInteger countObjectsFromPList = [[mdict allKeys] count];
NSLog(@"Objects in PList %d", countObjectsFromPList);

for(int i=0; i < countObjectsFromPList; i++){
  NSLog(@"\n\n\n%d\n\n\n", i);
  NSLog(@"from viewWillAppear- Object Name- %@", object);
  if([object isEqualToString:[[mdict allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]]){   
    NSLog(@"Already exists");       
    exists = YES;
    NSLog(@"The value of the bool is %@\n", (exists ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
  }
}
```

What I had to do is to remove the `=` in the `for` loop. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
id object = [mdict objectForKey:key];
BOOL exists = (object != nil);
```

Edit: apparently that wasn't clear enough.
Basically with `objectForKey` you're just telling the dictionary "could you please give me the object for my key `key`"? If the object is there for that key, the returning value will be non-nil. Otherwise it will be nil. That's why you check for `object != nil` in order to know if that object exists in the dictionary for your key. *goes to take more coffee*

Comment: You wanna check if an object with a specific key exists in a plist, (i.e. a dictionary), right? That's how you can do it.