# Check if exists a string inside a plist file

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiimage, plist, xcode4.5

Hello guys i try to check a single line STRING inside my plist file, in my detail view I need to implement a IF like a:

```
NSString *data = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"name" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:data];
self.myMutableDictionary = dataDict;


    if (name.text == [myMutableDictionary objectForKey:@"emittente"]){

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_on.png"];
        [Star setImage:image];

    } else {

        UIImage *favImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_Off.png"];
        [Star setImage:favImg];

    }
```

But dosent work, i think no reading inside the plist file, any idea or metod for do that?

Thanks.

Comment: this might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634057/how-to-check-whether-data-or-object-already-exist-in-plist-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code looks almost fine. Just check the following:

Does your plist contain the key `@"emittente"` **on the top level**? If not, you have to descend down your dictionaries or arrays to get to the right level.

Also, you are comparing pointers in your if statement, not strings. Use this instead:

```
if ([name.text isEqualToString:myMutableDictionary[@"emittente"]) ...
```

---

BTW: you should not use uppercase instance variable names.

Comment: My Plist is create with Root <array> <dictionary> <string> emittente </string><string>website</string></dictionary> and repeat for a few lines